# ZTE Open with Firefox OS as WiFi hotspot

Tags: wifi, firefox-os

I would like to use this Firefox OS device as WiFi hotspot (with a Mac).

I have noticed some slowness. Does anyone know if that might be due to the WiFi receiver/emitter in the ZTE Open being a low quality component?

Is there any software (Mac preferred) that might enable me to tell where does the low performance come from (connection to the network -speed/latency-, wifi hotspot data exchange)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question. One thing you could [test on the device itself with JavaScript](https://github.com/robnyman/Firefox-OS-Boilerplate-App/blob/gh-pages/js/webapp.js#L306), is the connection speed and if it's metered. Hardware could potentially come into play here as well.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the code (and quick answer). I have had a look and perhaps that will help. Is there specific documentation for the code? I am not familiar at all with this (FxOS?) API. Do you think the wifi hotspot connection is going to be tested?

Comment: There is some [basic documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Network_Information). I'm not sure about the hotspot, to be honest. Please test and see if it works for you!